# how to show only changed rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if want querying the following table :

```
EventDateTime (DateTime), Host (guid), Flag ( bit)
2013-04-01 05:00, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:01, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:02, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:03, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:04, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:05, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:06, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:07, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:08, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:09, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:10, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:11, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:12, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:13, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:14, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:15, {id-x}, 0
```

and the result should be:

```
2013-04-01 05:04, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:07, {id-x}, 0
2013-04-01 05:11, {id-x}, 1
2013-04-01 05:15, {id-x}, 0
```

i have try it with LAG,LEAD and OVER Clause. but no luck :(

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you provide more details along with CREATE table and some sample data and your expected results? That will provide you with accurate response.

Comment: Please also add the queries you have tried already.

Comment: Oh, so everytime the flag changes, you want that record?

Comment: i doesn't save my tried queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version for SQL Server 2012 using the new `LAG` feature:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        EventDateTime,
        Host,
        Flag,
        LAG(Flag)
            OVER (ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS PrevFlag
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT EventDateTime, Host, Flag
FROM CTE
WHERE Flag <> PrevFlag;
```

Here is a version for SQL Server 2008 using a self join:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        EventDateTime,
        Host,
        Flag,
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT
    C.EventDateTime,
    C.Host,
    C.Flag
FROM CTE AS C
    INNER JOIN CTE AS D
    ON C.RowNum = D.RowNum +1
WHERE C.Flag <> D.Flag;
```

Comment: This looks very slick... does it work?

Comment: Works perfectly. BUT: this only SQL2012 compatible, right?

Comment: @RoKa It does in SQL Server 2012. Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/963ae/1/0

Comment: @RoKa Yes, 2012 only. You would have to use a self join in previous versions.

Comment: I have added a version using a self join that works with 2008.

Comment: and, i learned a new site: sqlfiddle.com. i know jsfiddle, but this one is also great.